# How to add cleanup.policy to spring application.ayml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is it possible to add in spring application.yaml "cleanup.policy" and "log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms" for configure kafka compact? If it is possible, how?

Now I do it with @Bean NewTopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it via a `NewTopic` bean; you can set the value using a property placeholder, however.